# Kafka- Joining a Kafka Stream with a Global K Table using non key value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Ive seen multiple posting that state its possible to join a kafka stream with a global k table using record values instead on keys on the global k table
[https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
They allow for joining against foreign keys; i.e., you can lookup data in the table not just by the keys of records in the stream, but also by data in the record values.
```

Does that mean its possible to join a stream with a global k table using a record value of the global k table rather than the key of the global k table.

For Ex:

I have two objects / tables
Order --> orderId, order amount
OrderDetail --> orderDetailid, orderId, qty, price

Order will be converted in to a kafka stream with key orderId
OrderDetail will be converted in to global k table with key orderDetailId

OrderId is a foreign key in OrderDetail

Is it possible to perform a join on Stream(Order) and GlobalKTable(OrderDetail) with a non key value of OrderDetail
ie: A join on Order.orderId with OrderDetail.OrderId.
The intention here is to retrieve a list of Orders with all their Order Details

I looked at KStreamKTableJoinProcessor and noticed the process() method always searched for the key on the global k table.
I know its possible to select the key to be used on the Left Side (KStream), but is it possible to select a record value as the key from the right side (Global K Table) while performing the join.

One solution would be to recreate the global k table with orderId as the new key , but I dont want that as that would only create one orderId value in the Global K Table. Im trying to fetch a one-many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - no it's not possible to do a `KStream`-`GlobalKTable` join with a value from the table side, you can only use the value from the stream to match against the key of the `GlobalKTable`